# Ajax and HTML lossing html modification

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is the following one.

This is the method that allow me to change my index html depending if I am logged as an user or not, the problem is when I am connected in the web page during X miliseconds my index.html shows what's expected ( this method changes my index.html differentiating between the window from logged user and Anonymous ones) it shows an iframe which only  connected users can see.
But it suddenly returns to the initial state of my web page.

Some idea?

***index.html***

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#sendLogin').click(function() {  

        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "login.php",  
        data: $(formLogin).serialize(),
           success:function(data) 
            {
             if (data.toString().trim() == "Si") {
               $("#elementos").css('display' , 'inline');
             }
             else {
              alert ("No he entrado");
             }
            }
        });  
    });  
});
```

***login.php***

```
    <?php

include "conectarse.php";

//Obtener los datos de la pag web.
$usuario = $_POST['botonUser'];
$pass1 = $_POST['botonPass'];

//Procedo a conectarme a la Base de Datos
$link = conectarse($baseDatos);

$query_select = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND pass = '$pass1';";

$registro = $link->query($query_select);

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registro))
    {    
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['nom'] = $row['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['apellido'] = $row['apellido'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['tiempo'] = strftime("Hoy es %A y son las %H:%M");

    echo 'Si';

    }
    else {
        session_start();

        echo "No";
        $_SESSION['nom'] = "Anonimo";
    }

$link->close();

?>
```

Comment: Is #sendLogin a SUBMIT button?

Comment: Yes it's a submt button

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of a SUBMIT button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sendLogin').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        // the rest stays the same
        ...
```

Comment: I dont know why but when I add this, it doesn't show the alert message from success.

Comment: That could be another problem, like in your PHP... Please post some log info, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it adding onsubmit="return false" on the form.

Thanks!!